# "И мглой волнистою покрыты небеса" - грамматика?

Tags: грамматика

**И мглой волнистою покрыты небеса**. (Пушкин)

Сделайте, пожалуйста, грамматический разбор так, как сейчас в школе учат.
Особенно интересует слово "покрыты", а то несколько умных дяденек уже на третьем ресурсе договориться не могут, что оно такое по грамматической роли и как часть речи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...Люблю я пышное природы увяданье,
В багрец и в золото одетые леса,
В их сенях ветра шум и свежее дыханье,
**И мглой волнистою покрыты небеса,**
И редкий солнца луч, и первые морозы,
И отдаленные седой зимы угрозы.

["Провокационный", конечно, вопрос, но я попробую.]
Если бы это были не поэтические строки, "стандартное" оформление, возможно, было бы таким:
**Я люблю** пышное увяданье природы, леса, одетые в багрец и в золото, шум ветра и свежее дыханье в их сенях, **и небеса, покрыты[е] волнистою мглой**, и редкий луч солнца, и первые морозы, и отдалённые угрозы седой зимы.

Я бы, основываясь только на школьных знаниях, рассуждала так.
Я — подлежащее;
люблю — сказуемое;
люблю (что?) увяданье, леса́, шум, дыханье, **небеса**, солнца луч, морозы, зимы угрозы — однородные **дополнения**;
небеса (какие?) **мглой волнистою покрыты** — причастный оборот (**определение**), находится перед определяемым словом, поэтому запятыми не выделяется (покрыты[е] (чем?) мглой (какой?) волнистою).

Главная загвоздка здесь, я думаю, в слове *покрыты*.
Некоторые словари относят его к [причастию](https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9) (В. п. (неод.), мн. ч., страд. залог, прош. вр., изъявит. накл. слова «покрыть»), некоторые — к [прилагательному](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/220045/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Мне кажется, что это все-таки так называемое усеченное причастие.
Такие формы, наряду с усеченными прилагательными, часто используются в стилистической поэтической и народной речи:
сине море; добры молодцы; красно солнце отвечало; дает земле древесну сень; по сторонам животворяща древа; моляся кораблю бегущу...

Comment: Да! Вы блестяще нащупали болевую точку: **усеченное** причастие. Остался только вопрос, что оно такое, это самое усеченное причастие - и чем оно отличается от причастия краткого?! Без этого ваш блестящий ответ чуть-чуть не полон. И вот это уже не подвох. Я реально не понимаю, зачем вводить новую сущность. это самое "усеченное" причастие.  На самом деле не новую, Её использовали грамматисты  XIX  века (в интернете, например, есть грамматика Виссариона Белинского) - но как полній синоним "краткому".

Comment: Благодарю за добрые слова (нечасто Вы хвалите любителей). Мне нечего добавить к ответу (к великому сожалению!) — "столько много" филологических мозгов у меня нет. С Новым годом!

Comment: И очень жаль, что не можете. Вы употребили термин "усеченное причастие" - и не в состоянии объяснить, а что оно такое - и чем отличается от краткого?! Да ладно вы - никто не может. Я не нашел, где бы это понятие вводилось. А это нарушает все принципы систематики...