# Что такое "усеченное причастие"

Tags: грамматика

В ответе на вопросе ["И мглой волнистою покрыты небеса" - грамматика?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447614) всплыл термн "усеченное причастие".

Что это такое - и чем отличается от причастия краткого?

В интернете есть несколько упоминаний подобного, но лишь как констатация,сам термин не определяется.
У Белинского в "Грамматике" есть упоминание этого термина, но судя по всему, там им обозначается именно краткое причастие. И это единственное авторитетное мнение, найденное в Интернете.

Comment: Поправил опечатку в заголовке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что в том ответе данный термин (он обозначает архаичную языковую сущность) употреблен обоснованно: по форме это причастие, укороченное на один слог (краткие причастия в целом такого свойства не проявляют, хотя в том примере - совпадение) в интересах поддержания стихотворного ритма. Понятие *"усечённое прилагательное/причастие*" приведено как пример со словом "усечённый" в Малом академическом словаре  (М.: Институт русского языка Академии наук СССР. Евгеньева А. П.. 1957—1984).

Современная подробная статья: "Усечённые" причастия в русском литературном языке 18 века.

http://slaviachristiana.ru/files/library/zapolskaya/01%20-%20zapolskaja_VMU_85_3.pdf

Comment: Спасибо. Судя по всему, это единственный источник, из-за которого весб спор и разгорелся. Но ни в нем, ни у Трдиаковкого нет четкой аргументачии и критерия, чем отличаются "усеченные" формы от "кратких". Различный генезис постулируется на основании Тредиаковского (хотя у него, насколько понял, различий между "усеченными" и "краткими" формами не дается), а в качестве критерия  предлагается (косвенно) считать краткими формы с суффиксом Н - и только их. Последнее, имхо, ни в какие ворота не лезет.  Или я вообще ничего не понял.   Ладно, я перечитаю, коли больше ничего не остается.