# «Исполненны» (с двумя «н») в стихотворении Лермонтова

Tags: орфография, нн

> И чёрные глаза, остановясь на мне,
>   Исполненны таинственной печали, 
>   Как сталь твоя при трепетном огне, 
>   То вдруг тускнели, то сверкали.

Отчего две "н" в слове "исполненны"?

Comment: А где вам встретилось два н? Здесь скорее опечатка.

Comment: @Серж На [викислкаде](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)) только в старинном (дореформенном) издании одно "н", а в современных ПСС — два. В моём бумажном двухтомнике (который вышел в конце 80-х многомиллионным тиражом) тоже два "н".

Comment: @grizzly, в поисковиках мне не удалось найти две н.  А вот в корпусе языка слово исполненны с  двумя н. встречается. Но в основном в текстах конца 18 в. начало 19в.

Comment: @Серж Как Вы ищете?! Оно же [чаще встречается](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVxb_4lPnmAhXl8KYKHWltA5wQ_AUoAXoECAYQCQ&biw=1047&bih=465).

Comment: Да, я искал только фразу: Исполненны  печали. В любом случае, это ошибка.

Comment: Старых книг с таким написанием довольно много находится (если искать гуглом по одному слову). По нынешним нормам пишется одно -н-, у Розенталя есть даже прямой пример: http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2465

Comment: @Alex_ander,страдательные причастия всегда писались с одним н. Видимо, это ошибка, кочующая из издания в издание.

Comment: В данном контексте это _прилагательное_ (см. ссылку выше на Лопатина).

Comment: Краткие прилагательные пишутся с одним н, Полные с двумя н. У Лопатина: Душа исполнена печали; Но: исполненный (полное прилагательное).

Comment: У Лопатина это по причине _обязательности зависимых слов_ (исполненный чего). В общем же случае -нн- наследуется от полной формы прилагательного https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/n-i-nn-v-kratkih-prilagatelnyh Напр. очевидное _священны_.

Comment: Краткие формы прилагательных на -нный пишутся с одним н, если эти прилагательные требуют зависимых слов и не имеют формы сравнительной степени. ***Священный - исключение.***

Comment: _Священный_ **не требует** зависимых слов (а также _обалденный_, _первостепенный_, _благословенный_ и многие другие прилагательные с -нн- в краткой форме). Вряд ли возможен законченный список таких "исключений".

Comment: Священный не требует зависимых слов - я о том же. Хочу сказать, в слове священный два н пишется как исключение. Оно не подпадает под правила в справочнике ПАС.

Answer (score 1):

Идея, предложенная *Сержем*, мне кажется заслуживающей внимания (конечно же, имея такую же точку зрения, я поддержала его ответ).
Не лингвист я — всегда об этом говорила, — но думаю, что у Лермонтова и правда применено так называемое усечение (и в этом случае уже неважно, усечение *чего* — причастия или прилагательного).

Рассмотрим четверостишие — без деепричастного оборота ("остановясь на мне") и без сравнительного оборота ("как сталь твоя при трепетном огне"). Имеем:
*И чёрные глаза, исполненны*[е] *таинственной печали, то вдруг тускнели, то сверкали.*

Всё на своих местах: управление и время соблюдено, смысл понятен.

В подтверждение своего мнения привожу два *похожих* вопроса:
[“И мглой волнистою покрыты небеса” - грамматика?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447614/%D0%98-%D0%BC%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)
[Что такое “усеченное причастие”](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447655/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) (ответ дал *Alex_ander*)

Comment: эээ... Кто-то из серьезных грамматистов (кто такая Кулева, которую Серж называет лингвистом с с какого-то левого сайта,  мне неведомо) рассматривает понятие усеченного прилагательного в русском языке? И  второе. Чем "усеченное" прилагательное отличается известного нам краткого от краткого? Если ничем, то зачем плодить сущности?

Comment: PS "усеченные прилагательные" типа "гос" (госдолг), "арт" (арткафе) и прочие не предлагать. Это явно не то, что у кулевой, а тот факт, что Кулева в своих опусах воспользовалась "занятым" термином, тоже не говорит в её пользу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы что-то напутали. _Серж_ в ответе на вопрос (Что такое “усеченное причастие”) дает ссылку на Н. Н. Запольскую (https://inslav.ru/people/zapolskaya-natalya-nikolaevna), доктора филологических наук.

Comment: Не вижу ссылки. И не вижу у него термина "усеченное причатие". Вижу русским по-белому "см. статью А.С. Кулевой "К вопросу о происхождении усеченных ***прилагательных***". Наверное, вы умеете читать между строк.

Comment: А вот ссылка на первоисточник http://www.oshibok-net.ru/questions/991.html Если это написано Запольской, то я - царица Тамара.

Comment: (+) о том, что такое ***усеченные причастия***, я спрашивал (без особого успеха для понимания) тут https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447655. Если вам есть, что добавить - прошу покорно сию любезность оказать.

Comment: Каюсь! Каюсь! Перепутала авторов ответов. На Ваш Вопрос _Что такое “усеченное причастие”_ ответ дал _Alex_ander_. Там и есть ссылка на Н. Н. Запольскую: "Усечённые" причастия в русском литературном языке XVIII в. ( http://slaviachristiana.ru/files/library/zapolskaya/01%20-%20zapolskaja_VMU_85_3.pdf)

Comment: Ну так это совсем другое ))) Alex_andr -  вполне уважаемый мной автор. А у Серж... даже не заморачивается чтобы вникнуть в смысл им же цитируемого. Даже переспрашивать страшно.

Answer (score 0):

Если сходить в [Викитеку](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)), можно обнаружить оба варианта - и оба они имеют право на жизнь.

Я бы ориентировалась на [Лермонтов М. Ю. Полное собрание стихотворений в 2 томах](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)/%D0%9F%D0%A1%D0%A1_1989_(%D0%A1%D0%9E)), где этих "н" - два (как краткая форма отглагольного прилагательного).

Читаем [пояснения](https://repetitors.info/otvet/?t=46405):

> Осмелюсь предложить собственно придуманный способ разграничения
>   кратких отглагольных прилагательных и кратких причастий. Работает
>   очень хорошо, проверено не на одном поколении учащихся :) Так что,
>   надеюсь, учитывая все это, коллеги не осудят.
>
> 1. Если подходят (приблизительно, по смыслу) слова "плохой"/ "хороший" (то есть признак), то перед вами краткое отглагольное прилагательное
>      (в них всегда НН).
> 2. Если мыслится глагол, действие, то перед вами краткое причастие ( всегда Н).
>
> Если четко понимать "признак" или "действие" перед вами, то все
>   остальные рассуждения, как правило, становятся излишними.

---

> Помните только одно, что причастие - это всегда признак по действию (причастие от глагола), а прилагательное с действием никак не
>   связано (блестящий ответ и блестящая пуговица).

Comment: Галина, г-н Лопатин (как предержащая орфовласть) прилагательные с -нн- отбраковывает на предмет неотделимости зависимых слов: http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2465 К усечению в краткой форме приговаривает и "исполненный чего".

Comment: *...Тебя там встретит огнегривый лев, / 
И синий **вол, исполненный очей**, / С ними золотой орел небесный, / 
Чей так светел взор незабываемый.*

Comment: И синий вол, исполненный очей ( здесь: исполненный - полное прилагательное).

Answer (score 0):

Вот что пишут лингвисты сайта www.oshibok.net.

В данном случае мы имеем дело с примером так называемых "усеченных прилагательных", довольно часто встречающихся в русской поэзии XVIII-XIX вв. По мнению исследователей (см. статью А.С. Кулевой "К вопросу о происхождении усеченных прилагательных в соотнесении с историей имени прилагательного"), эти искусственные формы проявлялись усечением последнего слога или последней гласной окончания, чтобы слово соответствовало ритмике стиха. Данное явление можно классифицировать как поэтическую вольность, которая с развитием поэзии практически исчезла. В современных изданиях слово может встречаться как в авторской редакции (с двумя Н), так и в соответстии с правилом (с одной Н).

Answer (score 0):

> Отчего две "н" в слове "исполненны"?

Это спорный случай.
В этом значении - полный "чего?" (не "чем?"!) возможна трактовка как отглагольного прилагательного, а оно пишется с удвоенным Н. Судя по всему, до определенного времени так и поступали.

И на то есть явные резоны. С одной стороны, подстановка дополнения в творительном падеже невозможна, с другой - возможна замена на синонимичное "полный".
Все это само по себе еще не позволяет говорить о слове "исполненный" как о заведомом прилагательном, но сильно укрепляет эту версию.

В дальнейшем, возможно под воздействием более новой формы "исполненный - чем?" (о её нормативности свидетельствует Розенталь, "Управление в Русском языке" http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%22%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%22%3F+&all=x) исполненный стало трактоваться преимущественно или даже исключительно как причастие даже в форме "исполненный чего". Отсюда и появление одинарного Н в современных изданиях.

Во всяком случае это соображение хоть что-то объясняет.